# CURL error in BASH script

Tags: linux, bash, curl

So I have this tool , written in BASH, which gets updates regularly, and I used to display the changelog for it using CURL. Like this:

```
changelog=$(curl --silent -q http://website.com/changelog.txt)
```

It was working, but now it returns the following:

```
 Changelog:
 <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
 <html><head>
 <title>406 Not Acceptable</title>
 </head><body>
 <h1>Not Acceptable</h1>
 <p>An appropriate representation of the requested resource /changelog.txt could not be found on this server.</p>
 <p>Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.</p>
 <hr>
 <address>Apache (Unix) Server at website.com Port 80</address>
 </body></html>
```

Any ideas why this is happening now ? Or how to fix it ?

Comment: This file is no more available in the website.

Comment: What does this question have to do with `bash`?

Comment: Yes it is available.
And has to do with BASH because it's part of a BASH script-file ?

Answer (score 0):

> ...Or how to fix it ?

You are getting html error 406. That is related to some mismatch in request "accept headers", please see here:

http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html

Maybe you can get further details if you run curl with some additional parameters:

```
curl -D - --head  http://website.com/changelog.txt
```

Comment: Well, for what I've seen, the lastest security enchanment I did on my server (which was exactly mod_rewrite) is causing the issue. I'll have to forward the request over.. But, after I tried, same thing. Also am running latest CURL updates..